# Xamarin - Update Observable Collection Not Working

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-core, xamarin, observablecollection

I have a Xamarin project in which I have a Cart Page. I'm trying to update the data whenever I click on an add or remove button but it doesn't. Here's the code

```
public class CartViewModel : BindableObject
    {
.... 

private ObservableCollection<OrderDisplay> _ordersList;
        public ObservableCollection<OrderDisplay> OrdersList
        {
            get => _ordersList;
            set
            {
                _ordersList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

And then I have `AddTotal` where I try to update it. It is called when pressing the add or remove button

```
 private async void AddTotal(OrderDisplay oCart, int quantity)
        {
            decimal total = 0;
            int index = 0;

            if (oCart != null)
            {
                foreach (OrderDisplay obj in OrdersList)
                {
                    if (obj.Id == oCart.Id)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    index += 1;
                }
                OrdersList[index].Quantity = quantity;
                OrdersList[index].Total = quantity * OrdersList[index].Price;
                //OrdersList = null;
                //OrdersList = tempOrdersList;

                var order = await _apiService.GetOrderById(OrdersList[index].Id, token);
                order.Data.Quantity = OrdersList[index].Quantity;
                var orderUpdated = await _apiService.UpdateOrder(Convert.ToString(order.Data.Id), token, order.Data);

                if (!orderUpdated)
                {
                    await _messageService.ShowMessageAsync("Error", "Ha ocurrido un error.", "Ok", "");
                    return;
                }
            }

            foreach (OrderDisplay order in OrdersList)
            {
                total = order.Total + total;
            }

            LblTotalCart = string.Format("{0:N2}€", total);

        }
```

For context here is the view

[image]

I don't know how to do it. Please help.

**EDIT**

I tried doing it with `INotifyPropertyChanged` but gives me `NullReference`. I don't know if this is correct

```
public class OrderDisplay : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //public int Id { get; set; }
        //public int Quantity { get; set; }
        //public decimal Price { get; set; }
        //public decimal Total { get; set; }
        //public CrProduct Product { get; set; }

        private int id;
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }

        public int quantity;
        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return quantity; }
            set
            {
                quantity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Quantity");
            }
        }

        public decimal price;
        public decimal Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set
            {
                price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Price");
            }
        }

        public decimal total;
        public decimal Total
        {
            get { return total; }
            set
            {
                total = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Total");
            }
        }

        public CrProduct product;
        public CrProduct Product
        {
            get { return product; }
            set
            {
                product = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Product");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a useful description of the problem.  If you are saying that the changes to individual `OrderDisplay` properties are not reflected in the UI, then the likely cause is that `OrderDisplay` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: @Jason I already tried that as I say in my question but the changes aren't visible either way

Comment: It would be great to see full example of code. "click on an add or remove button but it doesn't" I think should be some code that adds or remove from `OrdersList`, without it the ListView will not be updated

Comment: @choper The method `AddTotal` is the one that I call when trying to update it. I'm trying to update the items inside of that list (price and quantity). Adding an item or removing it works fine.

Comment: you tried it on `CartViewModel`, NOT `OrderDisplay`.  You are modifying properties of `OrderDisplay`, therefore that is where you need to add INPC.

Comment: @Jason `OrderDisplay` is just the model fot the items that I'm showing in my cart. The names may be confusing

Comment: does `OrderDisplay` contain the properties for `Price` and `Quantify`?

Comment: and does it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @Jason  `OrderDisplay` is my model not a ViewModel. I don't know if I should implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the model itself

Comment: That is the source of your problem, as I have pointed out twice.  How you choose to solve it is up to you.

Comment: @choper I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my ViewModel not the `OrderDisplay` model, should I do that?

Comment: @Jason I don't know how to solve it that's why I asked

Comment: implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `OrderDisplay`.  Now that is the third time I've suggested that.

Comment: @robluc when you use Binding, to notify View about changes you need to use PropertyChanged event, with out it View will never know about any changes in you Model or ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is the mechanism that the UI uses to determine when it needs to update a bound property.  If you are changing property `P` on class `X`, then `X` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise a `PropertyChanged` event when `P` is modified.

an `ObservableCollection<T>` only raises events when items are removed or added from the collection.  It does not raise events when individual properties on the class `T` are modified.

Comment: I added this to my `OrderDisplay` model but it gives me `NullReference`. I'll update the code

Comment: Which specific line?  What is null?  A null ref is a very common C# exception and there are some pretty basic debugging steps you should do when you have one.

Comment: Already fixed the issue. I could achieve what I wanted. Thanks.